# How to fix 'Dict object has no attrubute key'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got this error, while i have attribute key there.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Acer/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37- 32/randomQuizGenerator.py", line 33, in <module>
states = list(capitals.key())
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'key'
```

I am new in Python btw. I follow along all of the tutorial.
and while my dict is here:

```
capitals = {'Alabama': 'Montgemory', 'Alaska': 'Juneau', 'Arizona': 'Phoenix', 'Arkansas': 'Little Rock', 'California': 'Sacramento', 'Colorado': 'Denver',
   'Connecticut': 'Hartford', 'Delaware': 'Dover', 'Florida': 'Tallahassee',
   'Georgia': 'Atlanta', 'Hawaii': 'Honolulu', 'Idaho': 'Boise', 'Illinois':
   'Springfield', 'Indiana': 'Indianapolis', 'Iowa': 'Des Moines', 'Kansas':
   'Topeka', 'Kentucky': 'Frankfort', 'Louisiana': 'Baton Rouge', 'Maine':
   'Augusta', 'Maryland': 'Annapolis', 'Massachusetts': 'Boston', 'Michigan':
   'Lansing', 'Minnesota': 'Saint Paul', 'Mississippi': 'Jackson', 'Missouri':
   'Jefferson City', 'Montana': 'Helena', 'Nebraska': 'Lincoln', 'Nevada':
   'Carson City', 'New Hampshire': 'Concord', 'New Jersey': 'Trenton', 'New Mexico': 'Santa Fe', 'New York': 'Albany', 'North Carolina': 'Raleigh',
   'North Dakota': 'Bismarck', 'Ohio': 'Columbus', 'Oklahoma': 'Oklahoma City',
   'Oregon': 'Salem', 'Pennsylvania': 'Harrisburg', 'Rhode Island': 'Providence',
   'South Carolina': 'Columbia', 'South Dakota': 'Pierre', 'Tennessee':
   'Nashville', 'Texas': 'Austin', 'Utah': 'Salt Lake City', 'Vermont':
   'Montpelier', 'Virginia': 'Richmond', 'Washington': 'Olympia', 'West Virginia': 'Charleston', 'Wisconsin': 'Madison', 'Wyoming': 'Cheyenne'}
```

I have the key attribute in my dictionary, i don't know which part is wrong actually.

I expected the result is like this:

```
 State Capitals Quiz (Form 1)

1. What is the capital of West Virginia?
    A. Hartford
    B. Santa Fe
    C. Harrisburg
    D. Charleston

2. What is the capital of Colorado?
    A. Raleigh
    B. Harrisburg
    C. Denver
    D. Lincoln
```

Comment: `Dict` really has no attribute `key`, it has `keys`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is keys not key.

```
states = list(capitals.keys())
states
```

Now to get corresponding values of these states.

```
[capitals[state] for state in states]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get a list of all of the states, or keys, within the dictionary, you can do the following using list comprehension:

```
states = [k for k in capitals.keys()]
```